# Android find nearest resources

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i'm trying to make an android app that finds the nearest resources on a map based on Google maps
i have these resources saved in a SQLite database
the function i used is this:

```
    protected void findClosestResources(LatLng mCurrentLocation, GoogleMap map,Context context){
            Double currentLatitude=mCurrentLocation.latitude;
            Double currentLongitude=mCurrentLocation.longitude;
            String selection=Main_Activity.CategorySelect;
            //Determine yhe closest resources by substrating Latitude and Longitude
            /*Location=Place.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+LOCATION_TABLE_NAME+
                    " WHERE "+selection+
                    " GROUP BY "+M_COLUMNS[4]+
                    " HAVING MIN(ABS("+currentLatitude+"-"+M_COLUMNS[1]+")) " +
                    "AND MIN(ABS("+currentLongitude+"-"+M_COLUMNS[2]+"))",null);*/
if (Location.moveToFirst()) {//select the first row in the cursor object
            while (!Location.isAfterLast()) {//verifies if it is the last row
                LocationList thisLocation= new LocationList(Location);
                getInformationAbout(Location);
                PlaceMakerOn(map);
                PlaceList.add(thisLocation);
                Location.moveToNext();//select the next row
            }
            Location.close();//close the connection with database
        }
```

this seemed to  worked at first glance but after upon closer inspection the results were not really accurate.
the picture below is an example: atm and bank resources were searched.
while the bank it found(blue marker) is indeed closest to the green and the ATM it found(orange marker) is not[image]

Since the bank has an ATM the ATM marker should not have appeared so far from the bank. since that would mean that, according to the function, the orange marker is closer to the green marker than the blue marker
What can i do to make it more accurate?

Comment: oh well guess i'm not cut out to ask these kind of questions since i seem get downvoted every single time i ask an android question without ever knowing why :(

Comment: i have updated the description hoping it is more clear( and hoping that that was the reason for the downvote) i hope someone can give me an idea to solve this puzzle

Comment: I'm not the down-voter but I have some tips for you. First, improve your question's formatting; "pretty" questions go a long way. Ask yourself: Is this nice enough to read? Second, try to be concise: Don't over-explain your situation that doesn't have any connection to the real problem. Remove all the unnecessary "noise"; Ask one thing and one thing only. Good luck!

Comment: i though that it wasn't clear enough that why added the extra details and didn't ask one thing? how could i optimize my existing code to make the result more accurate

Comment: @ridsatrio is this better?

Comment: Far better. Although the formatting could use some more work but it's getting there. Nice job! I for one now has some clue about what you're expecting and what your problem really is.

Comment: @ridsatrio formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for marker placement seems to work just fine. My main concern is now on the data itself. (The ATM and bank location data, to be precise.)

> What can i do to make it more accurate?

Well, take a second look to your data. If you're populating this data manually (e.g., you wrote those latitude-longitude points by yourself to a DB file, or someone is supplying you) then you should try to take a second look and improve it.

If you're pulling those ATM and bank location from an API (e.g., Google's Location API and/or Foursquare's) then what you see right now in your maps seems to really be the case. In other words, there are no problems at all: There are possibilities for a bank not to have an ATM nearby. Who knows?

All in all, the real problem here is not with your code. As the markers placed in that example you've supplied looks just fine (they're all in a reasonable position). I suspect the data used to populate those markers to be the real culprit.

Comment: well actually i have added the location manually and there is an ATM nearby i suspect it has to do with the curvature of the earth....

Comment: @fuseteam Extremely unlikely over such short distances.

Comment: yet this is my output...... while the closest orange marker should be https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5xv5m68suvocg9/device-2015-11-30-215206.png?dl=0

Comment: i have taken a second look at my data it is accurate appearingly i only needed a correction factor of 1/cos(lat) for longitudedifferece and to square both differences

Comment: actually now i think about it i just needed the correction factor and to treat both locations as vectors